# Switching between files, inside of VSC (Visual Studio Code)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've been trying to find some sort of an extension for this for a while, but it seems there is no extension or shortcut for this yet. Basically, I would like to be able to switch switch between files, up or down.

For example if I press Alt+Up, I would go from Program.cs to IRule.cs. And if I press Alt+Down, vice versa would occur

Perhaps someone knows of some sort of a workaround or maybe knows of an extension that can do this, which I was unable to find?

[image: Code files]